# Typescript How can I filter data by data range?

Tags: typescript, express, date, http, filter

I'm making a request to filter data by date range and send the results to the client, the results should be the tickets that were created between those dates but fore some reason I get a console error and I cannot figure out why?

```
    var before:Date = req.query.before;
  if(before !== undefined){
        //@ts-ignore
        var after:Date = req.query.before;
        var filteredData = tempData.filter(function(t){
        return res.send(new Date(t.creationTime) >= after && new Date(t.creationTime) <= before);      
        });
  }
```

this is the console error:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:558:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Project\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Project\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:264:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Project\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:158:21)
    at C:\Project\server\index.ts:48:20
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Project\server\index.ts:47:37
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Project\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Project\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)  
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Project\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client?rq=1 Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

> The function provided to the filter method of `tempData` will be evaluated on every `tempData` elements.

I changed that, I don't get console errors anymore but it does not get any result.

```
const before: Date = req.query.before;
if(before !== undefined){
    //@ts-ignore
    const after: Date = req.query.before;
    let filteredData = tempData.filter(function(t){
        return new Date(t.creationTime) <= before && new Date(t.creationTime) >= after;
    });
    TICKETS_AMOUNT = filteredData.length.toString();
    res.send(filteredData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function provided to the filter method of `tempData` will be evaluated on every `tempData` elements.

In the function provided to the filter, you call res.send() which send a response to the client. You can only call this method once when answering to a request, and you are calling this method as many times as there are elements in `tempData`.

Consider filtering the data first and then send it back to the client.

```
let filteredData = tempData.filter(function(t){
    return new Date(t.creationTime) >= after && new Date(t.creationTime) <= before;
});
res.send(filteredData);
```

There is another issue in your code: you have set both `before` and `after` variables to `req.query.before`.

Your statement `new Date(t.creationTime) <= before && new Date(t.creationTime) >= after;`  will always return `False` except if `t.creationTime` equals to `req.query.before`. That's why it's likely that `filteredData` would be an empty array. See [the filter method for a JavaScript array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for more details.

You should try (I assume that `req.query.after` is set):

```
const before:Date = req.query.before;
  if(before !== undefined){
        //@ts-ignore
        const after:Date = req.query.after;
        let filteredData = tempData.filter(function(t){
          return new Date(t.creationTime) <= before && new Date(t.creationTime) >= after;
      });
      TICKETS_AMOUNT = filteredData.length.toString();
      res.send(filteredData);
  }
```

I wrote a complete example.

```
interface DataType {
    name: string,
    date: Date,
}

let data: Array<DataType> = [
    {"name": "foo", date: new Date(2020, 5, 12)},
    {"name": "bar", date: new Date(2020, 7, 20)},
    {"name": "baz", date: new Date(2021, 2, 23)},
];

app.get('/filter-date-range', (req, res): void => {
    let result = data;

    if (req.query.before) {
        let before: Date = new Date(String(req.query.before));
        if (!isNaN(before.getTime())) {
            result = result.filter((e) => e.date <= before);
        } else {
            res.status(400).send("Unable to parse before date.");
            return;
        }
    }

    if (req.query.after) {
        let after: Date = new Date(String(req.query.after));
        if (!isNaN(after.getTime())) {
            result = result.filter((e) => e.date >= after);
        } else {
            res.status(400).send("Unable to parse after date.");
            return;
        }
    }

    res.json(result);
});
```

Just adapt `data` to your project.